# Taking Screenshot using Selenium 3.6 - Java - Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm not able to take a screenshot in my project.  I'm using Selenium 3.6 version with Java. Here is my code:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Unfortunately the "copyFile" gives the following error:

```
The method copyFile(File, File) is undefined for the type FileUtils
```

I have also imported all the required packages.

Can anyone help me to take screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Use `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. This imports the `FileUtils` class you need.

Guess you import wrong package

check these package should be there

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
```

Sample code:

```
public class Takenscreensshot {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("d:/ss.png"));
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. 

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; is showing an error
 "The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved"

Comment: Once I import **import com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;** this error goes in FileUtils but in copyFile the error shows as "The method copyFile(File, File) is undefined for the type FileUtils"

Comment: Still I'm not able to take screenshot, I've imported all the correct packages. but still the error remains same..

Comment: **import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;**

These are the imports

Comment: you got any issue on traceback or Log

Comment: **File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\Screenshot\\screenshot.png"));**

This is the codei used

Comment: "traceback or Log " I have not much idea about this

Comment: You can create a class and copy this code and see whar happenns also check image after execution  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        File src=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("d:/ss.png"));
        driver.close();

Comment: Now I have created a new project and I have used **selenium-2.53.1**, no I used the code and I got the screenshot.. Yes the code is perfect and produced the result, but why is it not working with **selenium-java-3.6.0** .. Anyway thank you, but could you please help me to resolve this issue in selenium-java-3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all `the "copyFile" is giving an error. It is saying "The method copyFile(File, File) is undefined for the type FileUtils"`. It may be possible **`FileUtils`** is having multiple definition within your imports. So the solution would be as follows :

- Use only:

  ```
  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
  ```

> OR

- Change your code as :

  ```
  File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
  org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
  ```

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

These are the imports

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("E:\\Screenshot\\screenshot.png"));

This is the code..

Comment: For once `Clean` all of your `Projects` in your `IDE` and simply use the line `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));` in your code.

Comment: When I used **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));** .. It is alsp showing error 
"org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved"

Comment: Now I have created a new project and I have used **selenium-2.53.1**, no I used the code and I got the screenshot.. Yes the code is perfect and produced the result, but why is it not working with **selenium-java-3.6.0** .. Anyway thank you, but could you please help me to resolve this issue in selenium-java-3.6.0

Comment: That means your `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` is not successfull. Remove the concerned `jar` file from your `Project`, `Clean` all the `Projects` from your `IDE`, `Close` your `IDE`, Take a `System Reboot`, Add the relevant `jar` back to your `Project` and `Run` your `Test`

Comment: Downgrading to **`Selenium-2.53.1`** is not a **Solution** rather you are covering up the real issue. Get back on `Selenium 3.7.1`. If my **`Answer`** have catered to your **`Question`** , **`Accept`** the **`Answer`** by clicking on the tick mark beside my **`Answer`**, just below the VoteDown arrow, so the tick mark turns Green.

Comment: I removed the jars and restarted and again i added 3.7.1 but error comes when I upgrade selenium.. 2.53.1 is not showing error..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String capture = "window.png";

    try {

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        byte screenshot[] = (byte[])((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(capture);
                fos.write(screenshot);

        }catch (Exception){ }
```

This works for me correct .

Answer (score 0):

In shot from Selenium 3.6.0 FiltUtils is not available, so need to use FileHandler.

Below are the changes

1. Replace `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` to `import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;`
2. Replace `FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);` to `FileHandler.copy(SrcFile, DestFile);`

Now the code to take screenshot looks as below

```
TakesScreenshot scrShot =(TakesScreenshot)driver;
File SrcFile= scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
File DestFile=new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+"screenshot.png");
FileHandler.copy(SrcFile, DestFile);
```

For more info you please take a look [here](http://learn-automation.com/how-to-use-filehandler-class-in-selenium-for-screenshot/).